# UITableViewCell dequeue. Cancel async sqlite call

Tags: uitableview, asynchronous, fmdb

On a tableview, i'm loading (async) data from a sqlite DB(using fmdb). (in cellforrow...)

My problem are that if the user scroll very fast, I get a lot of query pending\not cancelled.

how can I cancel the query when dequeue cell?

Thanks for your help